C# Windows Form opened maximized on Windows11 of Microsoft Surface Go 4
I created a simple c# winform application that has specific size.
When I run the app on my labtop it opened as I expectied.
But when I run the app on Windows11 of Microsoft Surface Go 4
it always opened maximised.
I've set the options like below :
ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
AutoScaleMode = false;
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

I expected that
the app opens with specific size at the center of screen but it's not.
